# Ao subir os arquivos usando Bootstrap eu preciso subir todos arquivos relacionado a Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, hospedagem

Estou com uma dúvida relacionada a subir arquivos usando o framework Bootstrap!

Achei bem pesado a pasta do site com uma página única, então fica a pergunta eu preciso subir todos arquivos bootstrap ou tenho que subir apenas o bootstrap.min.css?

Comment: Depende: se vc quer apenas usar os estilos CSS do Bootstrap, o CSS já basta. Porém, se vc quiser usar alguma funcionalidade JavaScript relacionada ao BS, aí terá que carregar também o .js do Bootstrap.

Comment: Então dentre esses arquivos no caso eu subo apenas o arquivo bootstrap.min.css?

Comment: Aí vc vai usar apenas os estilos do BS, relacionados ao layout. O BS tem algumas funcionalidades, como, por ex., um menu hamburguer... se vc quiser usar ele, vai ter que usar o JS.

Comment: Fim um teste retirando todos arquivos e deixando apenas os arquivos Bootstrap "linkados" no meu documento e o site não apresentou problemas, acho que cheguei aonde queria chegar, obrigado!

Comment: O BS só tem 2 arquivos: um .css e um .js

Answer (score 0):

Veja o template inicial sugerido pela documentação do Bootstrap, nele há o vínculo em 02 arquivos:

- bootstrap.min.css; e
- bootstrap.bundle.min.js.

Parte do código recomendada, em [Bootstrap/Starter template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template):

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
   
<!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Repare ainda, que utilizaram uma [CDN](https://www.cloudflare.com/pt-br/learning/cdn/what-is-a-cdn/), com isso o carregamento desses arquivos pode ficar ainda mais rápido para o usuário final que já tiver eles em cache no navegador. Diferentemente de precisar baixar eles novamente, salvos na sua hospedagem. É recomendável utilizar também, pode ser esse mesmo link disponível no template.